# Is it possible to store SHA 256 bit hash as an integer in a BIGINT column?

Tags: python, sql

Given a very large integer such as:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> h = hashlib.sha256("foo").hexdigest()
>>> h
'2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae'
>>> i = int(h, 16)
>>> i
19970150736239713706088444570146546354146685096673408908105596072151101138862L
```

I have tried creating a table in SQLite version 3.7.13 such as:

```
sqlite> .schema sha_table
CREATE TABLE "sha_table" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "sha_hash" UNSIGNED BIG INT NOT NULL
    );
sqlite> INSERT INTO `sha_table` (`sha_hash`) VALUES (19970150736239713706088444570146546354146685096673408908105596072151101138862);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM `sha_table`;
1|1.99701507362397e+76
```

Trying to convert that number back to the expected integer/hex doesn't work:

```
>>> i = int(1.99701507362397e+76)
>>> i
19970150736239699946838208148745496378851447158029907897771645036831291998208L
>>> "{:0>64x}".format(i)
'2c26b46b68ffbe00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

EDIT: Trying from the Python sqlite3 client doesn't seem to work either:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT sha_hash FROM sha_table")
>>> i = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
>>> i
19970150736239716016218650738648251798472370569655933119801582864759645011968L
>>>> "{:0>64x}".format(i)
'2c26b46b68ffbe00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you called `int()` on the actual return value of your query, or have you copied the scientific notation and pasted it in the other line?

Comment: @Hyperboreus I had just tried it directly in the shell, updated with an example using the sqlite3 client, which show the same result.  Thanks!

Comment: What is `type(cursor.fetchone()[0])`?

Comment: Umm.... SHA hash is 32 bytes. Sqllite's largest integer is 8 bytes. Something doesn't smell right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 256 bit numbers.  That is far (far) larger than `BIGINT` can store.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "sha_table" (
   ...>         "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   ...>         "sha_hash" UNSIGNED BIG INT NOT NULL
   ...>     );
sqlite> INSERT INTO sha_table (sha_hash) VALUES (9223372036854775807);
sqlite> INSERT INTO sha_table (sha_hash) VALUES (9223372036854775808);
sqlite> SELECT typeof(sha_hash) from sha_table;
integer
real
```

When you overflow, sqlite stores it as REAL (aka `float`).

So to answer your question, no, it is not possible to losslessly store a 256-bit hash in a 64-bit data type.  You'll need to pick a different data type to store it - textual or BLOB being your options, really.